# Get handles of ContextMenuStrip submenus

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu

I am developing a plugin for an application, and I must register any controls I create with my host application, else they do not receive any messages and are effectively disabled. Registration is performed using a control's window handle. ***(Please treat this part as a given, it is only a background as to why I need this.)***

In order to do this, for every winforms control I create, I use its `HandleCreated` event and `HandleDestroyed` event to recursively register/unregister the control's handle and any child controls it owns.

I can do the same thing with a `ContextMenuStrip`, and this is fine for the first level of items, but if any of those items have submenus, I do not know how I can get a handle to the sub-menu that has opened in order to register it.

The `ToolStripMenuItem` objects inherit from `System.ComponentModel.Component` and not from `System.Windows.Forms.Control`, so they do not have a `.Handle` property, nor `HandleCreated` and `HandleDestroyed` events.

See image for exactly which window I need the handle of (at time of creation).
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ToolStripMenuItem.DropDown.Handle`.

Comment: Doh! Missed it. I will use that together with the `opened` event. Thanks.